# Function list variable doesn't return the current state of a recursive variable

Tags: c#, recursion, unity-game-engine

I am working with a graph data structure and have a recursive function to calculate the depth of a node by counting the parents to the root node.

There are some other issues that I need to deal with, but for right now my main problem is to do with storing the *current* value of the recursive dictionary parameter, which stores the path branches.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Node {
    public string name;
    public int ID;
    public int maxDepth;
    public readonly List<Node> Dependencies = new List<Node>();
    public readonly List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();

    public bool isOrphan {
        get {
            return Dependencies.Count == 0;
        }
    }

    public bool isParent {
        get {
            return Children.Count != 0;
        }
    }
}

public class test {
    private static readonly List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>(); 
    public static void Main() {
        Node A = new Node() {
            name = "A",
            ID = 1
        };

        Node B = new Node() {
            name = "B",
            ID = 2
        };

        Node C = new Node() {
            name = "C",
            ID = 3
        };

        Node D = new Node() {
            name = "D",
            ID = 4
        };

        Node E = new Node() {
            name = "E",
            ID = 5
        };

        Node F = new Node() {
            name = "F",
            ID = 6
        };

        Node G = new Node() {
            name = "G",
            ID = 7
        };

        nodes.Add(A);
        nodes.Add(B);
        nodes.Add(C);
        nodes.Add(D);
        nodes.Add(E);
        nodes.Add(F);
        nodes.Add(G);

        A.Children.Add(B);
        A.Children.Add(G);
        B.Children.Add(C);
        B.Children.Add(D);
        C.Children.Add(D);
        D.Children.Add(E);
        E.Children.Add(F);

        B.Dependencies.Add(A);
        C.Dependencies.Add(B);
        D.Dependencies.Add(B);
        D.Dependencies.Add(C);
        E.Dependencies.Add(D);
        E.Dependencies.Add(G);
        F.Dependencies.Add(E);
        G.Dependencies.Add(A);

        foreach (Node n in nodes) {
            n.maxDepth = getMaxNodeDepth(n);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int getMaxNodeDepth(Node n, string listIndex = "base",
                    Dictionary<string, List<int>> paths = null) {
        bool firstIteration = false;

        if (paths == null) {
            firstIteration = true;
            listIndex = n.name.Replace(" ", "-");
            paths = new Dictionary<string, List<int>> {
                {listIndex, new List<int>(0)} 
            };
        }

        // Prevent the starting node from being added to the path
        if (!paths[listIndex].Contains(n.ID) && !firstIteration)
            paths[listIndex].Add(n.ID);

        // This variable should take the CURRENT path and store it; 
        // not the value after all the recursion has completed.
        // Right now, the current path is affected by the recursions, somehow...
        List<int> currentPath = new List<int>(paths[listIndex]);

        foreach (Node parent in n.Dependencies) {
            if (n.Dependencies.Count >= 2) {
                listIndex = parent.name;
                paths.Add(listIndex, currentPath);
            }
            getMaxNodeDepth(parent, listIndex, paths);
        }

        // Print out branches
        if (firstIteration) {
            string list = n.name + "\n";
            int listNumber = 1;
            foreach (List<int> iList in paths.Values) {
                list += string.Format("Branch#{0} -- ", paths.Keys.ElementAt(listNumber - 1));
                int total = 0;
                foreach (int i in iList) {
                    list += string.Format("{0}, ", nodes.First(x => x.ID == i).name);
                    total++;
                }
                listNumber++;
                list += string.Format(" -- ({0})\n", total);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(list);
        }

        // Order all paths by length, return the highest count
        // This is to be used to space out the hierarchy properly
        return paths.Values.OrderByDescending(path => path.Count).First().Count;
    }
}
```

When the foreach loop encounters a node with more than one parent, it creates a new branch and *should* populate it with the current IDs of the nodes.

`C   D
  \ /
   B
   |
   A
   |
  ...`

#### What should happen

Using the above example, beginning with A, it will first iterate B, as its direct parent. Then it begins on B's parents, which it has two of and because of this, it creates a separate branch and should fill that branch with B and its children (until the starting node, this time being A).

#### What actually does

Somehow, when B has finished iterating over C, `parent D` polls the current path and is returned `B, C`, where it should actually be just `B`, as C is a sibling, not a direct child or parent.

## Huge edit

The code I've attached runs completely out of the box and contains an example. You can see the result contains some anomalous results, such as

`F 
Branch#G -- E, D, G, A,  -- (4)`

which should actually be

`G
Branch#G -- G, A, -- (2)`

Comment: You haven't told us what you're actually seeing - and there's a lot of stuff here which is almost certainly irrelevant, and which is preventing us from reproducing the problem. I suggest you cut it down to a short, complete program - you may well find that as you do so, you find out what's wrong...

Comment: "a node can have multiple parents and more than two children" is definitely not a tree.

Comment: Added what I was actually getting (duh) and changed to `graph structure`

Comment: I'll create a dummy class Node and give you a full working example

Comment: Added runnable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a dictionary as a parameter to a method, the contents of the dictionary is not copied, only the reference to the dictionary is copied.
So altering the dictionary in one recursion branch will change the dictionary for the other branch as well.
To fix it, you can copy the dictionary explicitly yourself when passing the dictionary:
`getMaxNodeDepth(parent, listIndex, new Dictionary<string, List<int>>(paths));`

EDIT: Actually that wouldn't be enough either since it will copy the reference to the inner list and not the contents of the inner list, so you'll need a more nested cloning code:

```
    private Dictionary<string, List<int>> clone(Dictionary<string, List<int>>  map)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> clone = new Dictionary<string,  List<int>>(map.Count);
        foreach (var pair in map)
        {
            clone[pair.Key] = new List<int>(pair.Value);
        }
        return clone;
    }

    //And then call it from your code:
    getMaxNodeDepth(parent, listIndex, clone(paths));
```

However, assuming you don't need to fill this `paths` dictionary for outside code, and the only output here is the "maximum depth" of the node, you can probably simplify your code a lot, for example:

```
private int getMaxNodeDepth(Node n)
{
     if (n.Dependencies == null || n.Dependencies.Count == 0) return 1;
     return 1 + n.Dependencies.Max(parent => getMaxNodeDepth(parent));
}
```

EDIT: edited to add a solution that returns the "maximum path" as well:

```
    private List<Node> getMaxNodeDepth(Node n)
    {
        List<Node> path =
            n.GetSubFolders().Select(getMaxNodeDepth).OrderByDescending(p => p.Count).
            FirstOrDefault() ?? new List<Node>();
        path.Insert(0, n);
        return path;
    }
```

EDIT: and based on the comment from the OP, here's a solution that returns all available paths:

```
    private static List<List<Node>> getAllPaths(Node n)
    {
        if (n.Dependencies == null || n.Dependencies.Count == 0)
            return new List<List<Node>> { new List<Node> { n }};
        List<List<Node>> allPaths = n.Dependencies.SelectMany(getAllPaths).ToList();
        allPaths.ForEach(path => path.Insert(0, n));
        return allPaths;
    }

    private static int getMaxDepth(Node n)
    {
        return getAllPaths(n).Max(p => p.Count);
    }
```

Comment: That's what I had thought I was doing with `List<int> currentPath = new List<int>(paths[listIndex]);` originally, when that didn't work I tried a more worked out version as shown above- as it is a list of value type variables this should create or clone the list before the recursion happens? As of right now, it only returns the depth, but I may want to use the pathing data, which is probably why some have said it is convoluted (and rightly so)

Comment: Otherwise though, that is a beautiful piece of code, much more elegant

Comment: Edited with a simplified solution that returns the path as well (and use the Count property of the result for the depth).

Comment: Actually cloning the dictionary isn't enough because the dictionary values are lists, so in your first solution you actually needed to clone the lists as well, edited my answer to add it.

Comment: Using your second block of code (the code that only calculates depth, doesn't create pathing lists) on the example code I've added, I actually receive a `Sequence contains no elements` exception, regardless if it has parents or not

Comment: In case I wasn't explicit enough in my original post, the paths dictionary contains each path which is a list of node IDs. When a node has multiple parents (therefore paths) it creates a new list and populates it with the nodes that have been walked out at this point, then following through with those parents and its parents _ad infinitum_.

Comment: So basically, the function has an appallingly wrong name, should be `populatePaths()` and return a dictionary of all potential paths to a root node, if that makes sense

Comment: If that's what you want, then why a dictionary? You basically need a list of lists, right? Running on "G" will give a list with one list (G, A). Running on "D" will give a list with two lists (D,B,A) and (D,C,B,A), right? The key has no meaning...

Comment: I had initially used a list of lists, but I was unsure about how to properly maintain the pointer to the correct list for further branches, the current solution was one of desperation really, but if I were to change it I would add the branchname to that key (so as you go down one path the key name increases: "EDC": EFDCBA etc

Comment: I think I'm going to abandon the idea of mapping paths and instead just do as the method name suggests and only find the maximum path, seems too fiddly for me

Comment: I didn't understand your meaning of the key, I edited to post a solution that returns a list of lists (and also added a check for the exception in the earlier solution).

Comment: Note, in _Unity/Mono 3.5_ I found I had to explicitly use the lambda; `Dependencies.SelectMany(getAllPaths)` to `Dependencies.SelectMany(item => getAllPaths(item))`